# Is it possible to locate a place in India based on Pincode(627357) in google maps

Tags: search, google-maps

I am trying to implement a search option in my google map using pincode... Is it possible? Any suggestion....

Comment: Google Map for Indian users are updated and you can now search with Indian Pin code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  The Zip Code shown is in Madison, Wisconsin:

[maps.google.com/maps?q=53711](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=53711)

I imagine you are using some other method, but without more details this is by best guess.

Comment: Ahh.  Sorry, no idea.  But since you can add additional arguments, such as "Near=", perhaps you can add Indian states to the query and make it work.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer the question, but it may help others who search for it. Go to [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html). They do have an api to get location information from postal codes. The response contains latitude and longitude information. You can use this information to put on the map.

Below is a sample request and response:

> Request:
>   http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=627357&username=demo&country=IN

The following is the response:

```js
{
  "postalcodes": [{
    "adminName2": "Tirunelveli",
    "adminName3": "Tirunelveli",
    "postalcode": "627357",
    "adminCode1": "25",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "lng": 77.38515755863037,
    "placeName": "Karaiyiruppu",
    "lat": 9.042148763528974,
    "adminName1": "Tamil Nadu"
  }, {
    "adminName2": "Tirunelveli",
    "adminName3": "Tirunelveli",
    "postalcode": "627357",
    "adminCode1": "25",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "lng": 77.38515755863037,
    "placeName": "Nanajankulam",
    "lat": 9.042148763528974,
    "adminName1": "Tamil Nadu"
  }, {
    "adminName2": "Tirunelveli",
    "adminName3": "Tirunelveli",
    "postalcode": "627357",
    "adminCode1": "25",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "lng": 77.38515755863037,
    "placeName": "Naranammalpuram",
    "lat": 9.042148763528974,
    "adminName1": "Tamil Nadu"
  }, {
    "adminName2": "Tirunelveli",
    "adminName3": "Tirunelveli",
    "postalcode": "627357",
    "adminCode1": "25",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "lng": 77.38515755863037,
    "placeName": "Pallaikottai",
    "lat": 9.042148763528974,
    "adminName1": "Tamil Nadu"
  }, {
    "adminName2": "Tirunelveli",
    "adminName3": "Tirunelveli",
    "postalcode": "627357",
    "adminCode1": "25",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "lng": 77.38515755863037,
    "placeName": "Sankarnagar",
    "lat": 9.042148763528974,
    "adminName1": "Tamil Nadu"
  }, {
    "adminName2": "Tirunelveli",
    "adminName3": "Tirunelveli",
    "postalcode": "627357",
    "adminCode1": "25",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "lng": 77.38515755863037,
    "placeName": "Tenkulam",
    "lat": 9.042148763528974,
    "adminName1": "Tamil Nadu"
  }]
}
```